# Spring Cloud Apps Running in Container - Runs on Local Machine, Fails on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud

This is a follow up to an earlier question I asked on Stack Overflow. I am building a Spring Boot Cloud based service. I am running it in a container using Docker. I finally got it running on my local machine.

```
# Use postgres/example user/password credentials
version: '3.2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5000:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: psql_data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks: 
      - app
    restart: always
  config:
    image: kellymarchewa/config_server
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    networks:
      - app
    volumes:
      - /home/kelly/.ssh:/root/.ssh
    restart: always
  search:
    image: kellymarchewa/search_api
    networks:
      - app
    restart: always
    ports:
       - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - db
      - config
      - inventory
  inventory:
    image: kellymarchewa/inventory_api
    depends_on:
      - db
      - config
  # command: ["/home/kelly/workspace/git/wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh", "config:8888"]
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    networks:
      - app
    restart: always    
volumes:
  psql_data:
networks: 
  app:
```

Earlier, I was having difficulty relating to the dependency of the clients on the config server (the configuration server was not fully started at the time the clients tried to access it). However, I resolved this issue using `spring-retry`. Now, although I can run it using `docker-compose up` on my local machine, running the same command (using the same Docker file) fails on a virtual machine hosted by Google Cloud's Service.

```
inventory_1  | java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing
```

However, it appears to be querying the appropriate location:

```
inventory_1  | 2018-02-10 00:23:00.945  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://config:8888
```

I am not sure what the issue, since both are running using the same docker-compose file and the config server itself it starting.

The config server's application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
management.security.enabled=false
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=git@gitlab.com:leisurely-diversion/configuration.git
 # spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${HOME}/workspace/eclipse/leisurely_diversion_config
```

Client bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.application.name=inventory-client
#spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://config:8888
management.security.enabled=false
spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=true
spring.cloud.config.retry.max-attempts=10
spring.cloud.config.retry.initial-interval=2000
```

EDIT:

Upon further examination, it appears as if the config server is failing to pull the git repository that stores the application properties. However, I am not sure why this behavior is present because of the following:

- I have added SSH keys for GitLab to my VM.
- I can pull the repository from my VM.
- I am using `volumes` to reference `/home/kelly/.ssh` in my docker-compose file. The `known_hosts` file is included in this directory.
- The above (using `volumes` for my SSH keys) worked fine on my development machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I was able to resolve the issue. While this was actually resolved a couple of days ago, I am posting the general solution in hopes that it may prove useful in the future.

First, I was able to confirm (by using `curl` to call one of my server's endpoints) that the underlying issue was the inability of the config server to pull the git repo.

Initially, I was a bit perplexed - my SSH keys were set-up and I was able to `git clone` the repo from the VM. However, while looking over the [Spring Cloud documention](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR2/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_git_backend), I discovered that, the `known_hosts` file must be in `ssh-rsa` format. However, the VM's ssh utility was saving them in a different format (even though both my development machine and VM are running Debian 9). To resolve the issue, add the corresponding GitLab (or other host) entry in `ssh-rsa` format. Checking one's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` may also be of value.